# Como guardar una base de datos en PostgresSQL versión 14 sacado del enlace de este post y cuando acabo de hacer lo que diré que hice en este post?

Tags: postgresql

Usando la versión 14 de PostgreSQL sacado de este link https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads y habiendo corregido el error: File not found-please correct the binary path habiendo dado clcik en File-Preferences-Paths-luego donde dice PostgreSQL Binary Path copiado la ubiación del archivo bin donde tengo dicho gestor de base de datos en el espacio donde dice Select binary path... dado clic dentro del círculo que está debajo de Set as default y habiéndoseme formado un círculo dentro del circulo y dado clic en donde aparece el simbolo de un chuleado dentro de un portaplatilla dí clic y se validó correctamente y luego dí clic en Save y se guardó correctamente  y para solucionar ese problema intenté buscar en youtube como guardar una base de de datos en PostgreSQL pero solo hallé como exportarla o hacerle una copai de respaldo; por lo que necesito ayuda para guardar una base de datos en PostgreSQL